# Как использовать DKP от Delphi 7 в Delphi XE?

Tags: delphi

Есть DKP для Delphi 7, но на Delphi XE он не устанавливается, вместо этого создается новый проект и предлагается DKP пересобрать, но это тоже не выходит, так как нет исходников, а вместо них лежат dcu, но Delphi XE эти dcu почему-то не видит.

Comment: Если нет исходников, то никак. Скомпилированные пакеты и dcu жёстко привязаны к конкретной версии Delphi, в которой они были собраны.